# Not locating a word in an open .csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file that has the ticker of every NASDAQ stock currently live (nasdaq.csv), and I am wanting to go through my own .csv list of random tickers (finalsheet.csv) to determine if they are actually on the NASDAQ or not.

Example of nasdaq.csv (it has hundreds of symbols this is just an example):

```
Symbol
GOGO
WFT
QD
S
RIOT
```

Example of finalsheet.csv (it has hundreds of symbols this is just an example):

```
Symbol
PIH
TURN
FLWS
FCCY
SRCE
```

I have tried with this code to go through my own finalsheet.csv and see if there is a match to the nasdaq.csv.

```
import csv

nasdaqDatabase = r'C:\Users\Sterling\Desktop\StockProject\nasdaq.csv'

with open(nasdaqDatabase, "r") as f:
    with open(r'C:\Users\Sterling\Desktop\StockProject\finalsheet.csv', 'r' ) as theFile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(theFile)
        for line in reader:
            if theFile in nasdaqDatabase:
                print(line['Symbol'], 'has been located in the NASDAQ')
                break

            else:
                print(line['Symbol'], 'is not in the NASDAQ')
                break
```

I am stuck on how to continue, and this is my current error. If anyone has a suggestion as to how I should approach this differently or how to fix this that would be great!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sterling/Desktop/StockProject/learningnumbers.py", line 9, in <module>
    if theFile in nasdaqDatabase:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basic flow problem: `theFile` is your file handle, a descriptor of the open file.  It does *not* represent the strings stored on disk.   You need to iterate through the strings of the file.

Similarly, `nasdaqDatabase` is a file name, not the contents.  You need to read this into a structure of your choosing before you search for NASDAQ-listed stocks.

Extract the symbol from `line`, such as

```
if line['Symbol'] in nasdaqSymbols:
    print(line['Symbol'], 'has been located in the NASDAQ')
```

Does that get you moving?

Comment: I had to erase my last comment because something odd is occuring. It is going through the list of my sheet, but it is not correctly identifying all matches. For example QD is saying that it is being found in the NASDAQ sheet, but it is not. Why would it be falsely saying that?

Comment: That depends on the comparison type you're using.  Is there a longer ticker symbol that contains `QD`, and are you comparing individual strings with `in` rather than `==`?  That could cause such a problem.

Comment: Yes there are longer ticker symbols that contain QD and that could be potentially creating an issue. If I change the line of code to if line['Symbol'] == nasdaqDatabase: It then outputs my entire result to every symbol being not found in the the database which is obviously wrong. I am still very new to this language so perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: We need to see the code.  This should be posted as another issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('nasdaq.csv') as nasdaq, open('finalsheet.csv') as queries:
    nasdaq_txt = nasdaq.read()
    is_in = [query.strip() in nasdaq_txt for query in queries]
```

Now `is_in` is a list of booleans indicating if each line in `finalsheet.csv` is in `nasdaq.csv`